# Logo on Mesh is Mirroring

Tags: mesh, image

I've used a free human model to create a T-shirt. I feel great about the shirt, but I'm at the point where I need to put a logo in the center of the chest. I've looked up a few other threads and I'm running into a snag.

My logo is mirroring itself directly in the center of the shirt. At first, I thought it was because I hadn't applied the mirror modifier on my shirt mesh. I tried that and it still continues mirroring. I've tried adjusting the location, rotation and scale in the mapping node with no luck. Below are some screenshots. If If you need something I haven't supplied, let me know and I'll post ASAP. I appreciate your help!

[image: Overall look at my project]

[image: Close-up of T-shirt mesh]

Comment: If Mirror modifier was applied after unwrapping then chances are UV map is mirrorred i.e one side of the map is meant to be used by both sides of the mesh. This can be helpful, this can be huge problem. Try to look up your UV map and see if UV islands aren't intersecting

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. I want to upvote you, Mr. Zak, but I don't see a green checkmark. I'll come back to check later. Thank you!

Comment: There is no green checkmark on comments, only on answers.

Comment: If you answer your question there will be possibility to accept it (just add some details on how to achieve the result you found useful with e.g. screenshots etc) or someone else will add answer instead.  You can add answer in the Answer box below

Comment: I'm so sorry guys. I get that these are comments, but Mr. Zak, don't you have to put your answer from above into the answer box below for me to click the green checkmark?

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Zak had it right. I had accidentally applied the mirror modifier to my shirt after I had unwrapped it. Went back a few steps, applied the mirror modifier and then unwrapped. Worked like a charm!